# Get Body of MockEndpoint

Tags: apache-camel

How can I get the body of MockEndpoint?

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:end")
protected MockEndpoint endEndpoint;

endEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(1);
String test = (String)endEndpoint.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody();
```

endEndpoint.getExchanges() returns empty list and throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. However, endEndpoint does get 1 message.

Answer (score 2):

You should get it after you send the message to that endpoint and not before. So, after template.send..